# How to install "Nvim-R plugin" in vim at ubuntu?

Tags: r, vim, plugins

Im using ubuntu and have vim, I would like to install the plugin Nvim-R, which is a plugin to work with R in vim. I have vundle inside vim.

Comment: If you cant  give a tip or a help then do not spend time in writing, Im asking for people who could and want to give a hand no matter which is the question. Not everybody is an expert and have the same level of programming. Thanks for understand.

Comment: Jo te hi pu an a jo a tu ma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the [Nvim-R plugin](https://github.com/jalvesaq/Nvim-R) page it says:

> If you use a plugin manager, such as vim-plug, Vundle or Pathogen, follow its instructions on how to install plugins from github.

Then on the [vundle](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim) page you can see that you just need to:

> Launch vim and run :PluginInstall
>
> To install from command line: vim +PluginInstall +qall

and don't forget to add the vundle stuff to your `.vimrc` (as said on the above mentioned site)

Comment: Thanks for your time "bamphe". I have intalled vim 8.0, vundle and Plugin 'jalvesaq/Nvim-R' ,then tried again and it worked. I got R code highlighted with colors when I opened it at the linux shell:  $ vim test1.R

Comment: Glad that it helped :)